# Thymeleaf nested each and array indexes

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

I have a nested each structure that loops through a tree. Html code is as follows:

```
<div th:each="group : ${groups}" class="row corp-teams-group-row">
    <h2 th:text="'- ' + ${group.name}">GROUP NAME</h2>
    <div th:each="team : ${group.teams}" class="row corp-teams-teams-row">
        <h2 th:text="'- ' + ${team.name}">TEAM NAME</h2>
        <div class="col-xs-6 corp-man-wrapper corp-admin-wrapper">
            <div class="corp-user-image-container">
                <div class="corp-user-image-wrapper">
                    <img th:src="${team.users[0].image}">
                </div>
                <div class="corp-bugcount"><span th:text="${team.users[0].score}"></span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="corp-user-data-container">
                <h2 th:text="${team.users[0].name} + ' ' + ${team.users[0].surname}"></h2>
                <div class="corp-user-email" th:text="${team.users[0].email}"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 corp-man-wrapper">
            <h3 th:text="${team.newFeatureCount}"></h3>
            <h3 th:text="${team.defectCount}"></h3>
        </div>
        <div th:each="user : ${team.users}" class="col-xs-6 corp-man-wrapper">
            <div class="corp-user-image-container">
                <div class="corp-user-image-wrapper">
                    <img th:src="${user.image}">
                </div>
                <div class="corp-bugcount"><span th:text="${user.score}"></span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="corp-user-data-container">
                <h2 th:text="${user.name} + ' ' + ${user.surname}"></h2>
                <div class="corp-user-email" th:text="${user.email}"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The admin user is 0th index of each user array. But the notation to reach it obviously fails. I can confirm that the back-end data is correct.
I get this error when this code runs on the server:

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
>   processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception
>   evaluating SpringEL expression: "team.users[0].score" (teams)

I can't figure out what is wrong with this code and no similar examples on the net that cracks this problem. Thanks.

Comment: What's the root cause? The "Exception evaluating SpringEL expression" is just the outermost exception. Look at the last one to see the cause.

Comment: Yes it has a third caused by at the bottom and it says "org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1025E:(pos 10): The collection has '0' elements, index '0' is invalid"

Comment: Well, there's your problem.

Comment: Then this is your answer ;-) Then add an th:if if it this case could occur

Comment: You can write this as a solution and I'll accept as an answer thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments: the cause of the exception is

```
"org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException‌​: EL1025E:(pos 10): The collection has '0' elements, index '0' is invalid"
```

Simply add an th:if condition if the `team.users` can have zero elements.